# URL Shortening in Apache 2

Tags: php, ubuntu, url-rewriting, apache2

I have a site with homepage as `/var/www/mysite/index.html` 
Now I want to direct `www.mysite.com/x2312d` to `/var/www/mysite/app/pass.php?id=x2312d`
How do I do this?
Where should I create `.htaccess` file and what should be the contents of it?

Comment: hey take a look at these. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html http://forum.modrewrite.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3102 they should get you started. Now go forth and learn. If you have a specific problem come back with that.

Comment: @martswite it is a specific problem, tho its been asked a zillion times

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone I wouldn't say it was _specific_, the question is very general in terms of rewriting. Also no evidence is given as to what the OP has already tried/investigated. Now if he said, I've done 1,2,3 and the above doesn't work what is wrong, then that'd be _specific_. As it stands this is a "give me teh codez" question :-P

Comment: i totally agree!!! give me teh codez happens allot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your root `/var/www`

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /app/pass.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi I did this and its giving 404. My document root in sites-available/default is /var/www  . Is that a problem?

Comment: np, modrewrite is can be complicated at first, check out: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php for ways todo most things with rewrite in layman's terms

Answer (score 1):

put the .htaccess file in /var/www/mysite/app/. I'm assuming your docroot is /var/www/mysite/

make sure apache 2 has the rewrite module enabled

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#allows you to still access static items in this dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|gif|png|jpe?g)$

#sent it all to pass script
RewriteRule (.*)$ pass.php [L]
```

I like this method, assuming pass is some sort of controller. My controller for a rest api parses the /x23123d manually from the $_SERVER global var, but you could use a different rewriterule to have it be in the $_GET/$_REQUEST['id'] global var.

something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.+)$ app/pass.php?id=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Good References: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

edit: almost forgot, don't forget to handle trailing slashes too.